# Можно ли сделать гобальную разметка xml-элементов

Tags: java, android, xml

Суть заключается в следующем: есть три activity, и, разумеется три layout. Есть переходы между этими activity и я хотел узнать, можно ли сделать так, чтобы разметку кнопок для переходов по этим activity поместить в какой-то глобальный файл, чтобы не прописывать их в каждом layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких целей в layout можно сделать отдельный файлик:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete"/>

</merge>
```

и дальше на месте где должны быть кнопки сделать include:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/buttons_layout"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

[Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) по данному вопросу и [неплохой туториал](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/include-merge-tag)

Comment: добавлю, что так же можно сделать отдельный style для кнопки (если это 1 элемент, а не сложный из нескольких View) или сделать свою собственную View для таких целей.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @АлексейВакуленко, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.